# binary tree code does not work properly

Tags: c, pointers

I made a tree structure, read words from file and registered them to the tree. But the `enter()` does not work properly. I debuged with gdb and set a break point line 42. Then I entered `print *node` `print *root`.

```
(gdb) print node
$9 = (struct node *) 0x603250
(gdb) print *node
$10 = {left = 0x0, right = 0x0, word = 0x0}
(gdb) print root
$11 = (struct node *) 0x0
(gdb) print *root
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Why does `root` points nothing?
Why does not `node->word` point given word?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node {
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  char *word;
};

static struct node *root = NULL;

void memory_error(void) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory\n");
  exit(8);
}

char *save_string(char *string) {
  char *new_string;

  new_string = malloc((unsigned) (strlen(string) + 1));

  if (new_string == NULL)
    memory_error();

  strcpy(new_string, string);

  return (new_string);
}

void enter(struct node *node, char *word) {
  int result;

  if (node == NULL) {
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (node == NULL)
      memory_error();

    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->word = save_string(word);
    return;
  }

  result = strcmp(node->word, word);

  if (result == 0)
    return;

  if (result < 0)
    enter(node->right, word);
  else
    enter(node->left, word);
}

void scan(char *name) {
  char word[100];
  int index;
  int ch;
  FILE *in_file;

  in_file = fopen(name, "r");
  if (in_file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to open %s\n", name);
    exit(8);
  }

  while (1) {
    while (1) {
      ch = fgetc(in_file);

      if (isalpha(ch) || (ch == EOF))
    break;
    }

    if (ch == EOF)
      break;

    word[0] = ch;
    for (index = 1; index < sizeof(word); index++) {
      ch = fgetc(in_file);
      if (!isalpha(ch))
    break;
      word[index] = ch;
    }

    word[index] = '\0';

    enter(root, word);
  }

  fclose(in_file);
}

void print_tree(struct node *top) {
  if (top == NULL)
    return;

  print_tree(top->left);
  printf("%s\n", top->word);
  print_tree(top->right);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Wrong number of parameters\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "       on the command line\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage is:\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "         words 'file'\n");
    exit(8);
  }

  scan(argv[1]);
  print_tree(root);
  return (0);
}
```

I gave this program the following text as a argument "a.txt".

```
apple
orange
lemon
banana
pine
stroberry
ruby
perl
python
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never assign any value to `root`. Remember, C passes arguments by value, so when you call `enter(root, word);` from `scan()`, `enter()` can't change the value of `root`. It changes its local copy of it, though, but that is not enough.

The same problem occurs when you recursively call `enter`.

One way of fixing this could be to pass a pointer to the node pointer, so you can change it that way:

```
enter(&root, word);
```

with this declaration:

```
void enter(struct node **nodep, char *word) {
```

and adapt all uses of `node` inside it to become `*nodep`.

Answer (score 5):

At no point do you ever assign `root`. Therefore it will always stay `NULL`.

Note that, in `enter`, you allocate a node but don't actually save the resulting node anywhere. You may want to return the new node and do `root = enter(root, word)` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, if for some reason you don't want to return `root` (because, say, you want to return an error code), you have the option to pass a pointer to `root`, so that you can assign `root` inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

as @nneonneo pointed out, you should either return the newly modified root, or pass root as a pointer reference, having `void enter(struct node **node, char *word)` and calling it with `enter(&root, word);`

Answer (score 0):

You assign node in enter(), but since it's passed by copy, not reference, node is not changed outside the function.

Either return the new node `root = enter(root, word)` or pass by reference: `enter(&root, word)`, changing the footprint of enter to `void enter(struct node **node, char *word)` and all the instances of node within to *node.